# Catch SIGNAL SQLSTATE message using CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I am using a *stored procedure* for login to my website and I am displaying different messages on different conditions for different users in my stored procedure.

Now I don't want to show these MySQL error messages to my user, I want to display normal message. So can anyone tell me how to catch these error message.

I am using **codeIgniter** (PHP) framework.

Here is the code I have tried :

```
public function authenticate($email, $password) { 
       $query = ""; 
       try
       { 
          $query = $this->db->query('CALL LOGIN("'.$email.'","'.$password.'")'); 
          if($query->num_rows() == 1) 
          { /* do some thing here */ } 
       }catch(Exception $e)
        { echo $e;} 
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code snippets you tried so far.

Comment: public function authenticate($email, $password)
    {
 $query = "";
 try{
   $query = $this->db->query('CALL `LOGIN`("'.$email.'","'.$password.'")');
      
   if($query->num_rows() == 1) 
        {
  /* do some thing here */
  }                                                                                             }catch(Exception $e){ echo $e;}
 }

Comment: In PHP, if MySQL uses `SIGNAL SQLSTATE` - it will be interpreted as a PHP `Exception` and the message will be contained in the exception object.  Change your `echo $e` to whatever you want to show to the user.

Answer (score 0):

To catch errors raised by `SIGNAL,` use `GET DIAGNOSTICS` inside an exception handler

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/get-diagnostics.html

Comment: thanks for the link..@Marc Alff.                                                                 Marc Is there any other way to get the message more easily?